# How to sort an array of objects with amount and running balance keys

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to reorder a nested array that has date, amount and balance columns. The balance column is pre-populated and is the source of truth for the order within items of the same day.

Sorting by day descending is the first step, however I am trying to return the order of transactions within a day to be correct according to the balance.

Given row "a" below, `a.Amount + b.Balance` should equal `a.Balance`. In the real dataset a single day would have less than 50 transactions and the same balance showing up twice within a day is very rare and maybe not something to account for.

Out of order:

```
[
    { date: 190105, amount: -40, balance: -10},
    { date: 190105, amount:  50, balance:  40},
    { date: 190104, amount: -20, balance:   0},
    { date: 190104, amount:  30, balance:  30},
    { date: 190103, amount: -10, balance:  20}
]
```

Correct order:

```
[
    { date: 190105, amount:  50, balance:  40 },
    { date: 190105, amount: -40, balance: -10 },
    { date: 190104, amount:  30, balance:  30 },
    { date: 190104, amount: -20, balance:   0 },
    { date: 190103, amount: -10, balance:  20 }
]
```

The first thing I tried was array.sort like below but this doesn't work as items don't necessarily need to be moved up or down depending on the check below, only moved to the index (so above) of the item that matches:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.amount + b.balance - a.balance;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @spangle, I've edited the question. I do have a mess of working code trying to do figure this out manually, but I asked the question because I thought perhaps there was a simple way to do this that I didnt know about. I've specifically added my array.sort attempt since that is where I thought a solution might lie.

Comment: Removed the downvote, thanks for posting your attempt :) Will take  a look. One thing I like to use when working with objects is a for in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The key is that the unique item in the sorted array is the last one, since this won't match the check we use to find next items (since there are none below it).

So if you isolate the last item then you can loop through the rest and build up the sorted array on top of it.

I think my examples above were a bit confusing with the dates and multiple same rounded numbers, the data in the working snippet below is more realistic.

```js
var data = [
  { order: 10, amount: -3, balance: -257 },
  { order: 4, amount: -28, balance: 1280 },
  { order: 17, amount: -344, balance: 208 },
  { order: 13, amount: -27, balance: 74 },
  { order: 1, amount: -14, balance: 1986 },
  { order: 16, amount: 5, balance: 213 },
  { order: 8, amount: -129, balance: 1659 },
  { order: 14, amount: -113, balance: 101 },
  { order: 2, amount: 800, balance: 2000 },
  { order: 9, amount: 2045, balance: 1788 },
  { order: 11, amount: -216, balance: -254 },
  { order: 6, amount: -49, balance: 1310 },
  { order: 15, amount: 1, balance: 214 },
  { order: 5, amount: -2, balance: 1308 },
  { order: 12, amount: -112, balance: -38 },
  { order: 3, amount: -80, balance: 1200 },
  { order: 7, amount: -300, balance: 1359 }
];

var sorted = [];

// the last item is the one that 
// doesn't have a balance match with any other item
// and is our starting point to figuring out the order
function findLastItem(a) {
  var alength = a.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < alength; i++) {
    var matched = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < alength; j++) {
      var checkBalance = a[i].amount + a[j].balance - a[i].balance;
      if (checkBalance == 0) {
        matched = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (matched === false) {
      sorted.push(a[i]);
      a.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}

// now loop through matching transactions
// start matching against the last item we found above
// and build the sorted array bottom up
function sortItems(a) {
  for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var matched = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      var checkBalance = a[j].amount + sorted[0].balance - a[j].balance;
      if (checkBalance == 0) {
        sorted.unshift(a[j]);
        a.splice(j, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

findLastItem(data);
sortItems(data);
console.log(sorted);
```